# sql select data to right of hyphen

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

What AS400 SQL Select will retrieve only the data right of the hyphen?

```
shoes - Nike Reds
kids shoes - Converse
Boot - Gold Redwing
mens boot - timberland
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of the [`POSITION`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref2.doc/rbafzmst241.htm) and [`SUBSTR`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref2.doc/rbafzmst264.htm) functions:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Field, POSITION('-' IN Field) + 1)
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use POSITION (or POSSTR()) to find the position of the hyphen. Increment by one to find the next position.

You can use SUBSTR() and start from the position that you have found above.

Finally, you probably want to TRIM() it.

If your data sometimes does not contain a hyphen, that will need to be worked in as well.

```
select TRIM(SUBSTR(MY_FIELD_NAME,POSITION(MY_FIELD_NAME,'-')+1))
from MY_TABLE_NAME
```